# Arango particular extremly slow, why?

Tags: arangodb

My ArangoDB is particular extremely slow. Sometimes I get `503` from webserver. Attached screenshot shows some spikes in requests/transfer. Has anybody an idea, what's going on here?

[image]

Comment: We will need a lot more information if we are to help you. Can you detail what is going on in the server when the slow down happens? Are there any queries running? Anything else running on the machine? etc... Please update your question

Comment: We'd love to help you, but please https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Arango is slow when there are no indexes created and you have nested queries. Try to run explain command from web interface and see where your time goes. Then create the necessary persistent indexes.